# Is it possible to put create ggplots through functions to automate the production of graphs in R

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, dplyr, tidyverse

I need to create multiple charts from a set layout and wondering if its possible to put functions from dplyr and create my own function.

```
graph_plot <- function(x) {

gp1 <- select(var1, var2) %>%
ggplot(aes(x = var1, y = var2) %>%
geom_bar()

return(gp1)
}

graph_plot(x)
```

I am getting error messages saying var1 is not found. Any suggestions?

Comment: You didn't specify your data in front of `select`.

Comment: Incidentally, (1) no need for `return()`; (2) no need to define `gp1`: you can directly return the plot without first assigning it to a variable.

Comment: Yes, it's possible.  But you need to understand how `ggplot()` and the rest of the tidyverse use non-standard evaluation [NSE](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/articles/programming.html).

Comment: @Limey Not in OP’s case, no. Their code would work but for the omission pointed out by Park.

Comment: @Park lol wow. something so simple i overlooked. Many thanks!

Comment: @KonradRudolph  Ah!  I was distracted by the unused argument `x` in function signature.

Comment: There's a section on programming with ggplot2 in [the book of the same name](https://ggplot2-book.org/programming.html)